# teraterm macros that increment pause time value with each loop

Tags: teraterm

```
counter=0

:start_loop

sendln 'shutdown'
pause x

sendln 'no shutdown'
pause y

x= x+1
y= y+1

counter = counter + 1

goto start_loop
```

Please help me modify this script to make the 'pause' value increment by 5 seconds for each of the next loops.